# C# Получение тела ответа сервера 404

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Как получить тело ответа, если сервер отвечает 404?
Ниже код, которым отправляю запрос, при ответе выкидывает WebException, в котором тела ответа нет, хотя если отловить запрос Fiddler'ом, тело есть.

```
public static string Send(string body, string QueryUri, string ReqMet) {
    var BodyByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
    var Request = WebRequest.Create(QueryUri) as HttpWebRequest;
    Request.Method=ReqMet;
    Request.ContentType="application/json";
    using (var requestStream = Request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(BodyByte, 0, BodyByte.Length);
    }
    using(var response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse()) {
        using(var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828843/webexception-how-to-get-whole-response-with-a-body Вероятно это

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string Send(string body, string QueryUri, string ReqMet)
{
    var BodyByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
    var Request = WebRequest.Create(QueryUri) as HttpWebRequest;
    Request.Method = ReqMet;
    Request.ContentType = "application/json";
    using (var requestStream = Request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(BodyByte, 0, BodyByte.Length);
    }
    try
    {
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) Request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```